# Xcode subproject path relativity

Tags: xcode, frameworks, workspace

I have a workspace, Application.xcworkspace, that builds two frameworks and an executable that uses those frameworks. Here is roughly how they are laid out:

- Framework_1 - Built and output to a workspace-relative DerivedData path.
- Framework_2 - Depends on Framework_1, which is copied to a Frameworks area of the project and specified in the "Link Binary with Libraries" Build Phase, and output to a workspace-relative DerivedData path.
- Application - Depends on Framework_1 and Framework_2, which are copied to a Frameworks area of the project and specified in the "Link Binary with Libraries" Build Phase. Output directory is to a workdpsave-relative DerivedData path.

Each framework shows up in the workspace individually, but Framework_1.xcodeproj and Framework_2.xcodeproj are also displayed under Application as subprojects.

One problem I am having is when I copy the entire source tree to another folder and open the workspace, one of the subprojects shows as red. Upon cracking open the project.pbxproj file in the contents of Application.xcodeproj, I found that in the PBXFileReference section, the framework project that shows up properly has a relative path and the sourceTree attribute is "group" For the framework project that shows up in red, there is an absolute path, and sourceTree is "absolute"

I can manually edit the pbxproj file to make the second one relative, but that seems a bit extreme. Does anyone know of a way to change that attribute from the Xcode UI? Any help appreciated!